# SQL SCOPE_IDENTITY Recording twice

Tags: asp.net, sql, scope-identity

I have a stored procedure as

```
 @user1 uniqueidentifier , 
 @user2 uniqueidentifier , 
 @mesaj_text varchar(500),
 @mesaj_read int
 AS

 BEGIN
 declare @chat_id int
 IF EXISTS (SELECT chat_id FROM chat where user1=@user1 and user2 =@user2 or       user1=@user2 and user2 =@user1) 
    BEGIN   SELECT @chat_id =chat_id FROM chat where user1=@user1 and user2 =@user2 or user1=@user2 and user2 =@user1
    INSERT INTO mesaj values (@chat_id,@user1,@mesaj_text,getdate(),@mesaj_read) END
ELSE insert into chat values (@user1,@user2)
    SET @chat_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    insert into mesaj values (@chat_id,@user1,@mesaj_text,getdate(),@mesaj_read)
```

Everything is ok.

But recording twice "mesaj".Getting first inserted id of "mesaj" and using it as chat_id for second record.
So recording twice.(mesaj means message in Turkish :) ) .I tried to use @@IDENTITY instead of SCOPE_IDENTITY but nothing change.I tried to use IDENT_CURRENT(chat) but return error "Invalid column name 'chat'."

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: You've missed `begin` ... `end` from the `else` block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap everything after your `ELSE` in a `BEGIN` and `END` to keep it all as conditional to the `IF`.

```
@user1 uniqueidentifier , 
@user2 uniqueidentifier , 
@mesaj_text varchar(500),
@mesaj_read int
AS

BEGIN
    declare @chat_id int
    IF EXISTS (SELECT chat_id FROM chat where user1=@user1 and user2 =@user2 or user1=@user2 and user2 =@user1) 
    BEGIN   
        SELECT @chat_id =chat_id FROM chat where user1=@user1 and user2 =@user2 or user1=@user2 and user2 =@user1
        INSERT INTO mesaj values (@chat_id,@user1,@mesaj_text,getdate(),@mesaj_read) 
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN       
        insert into chat values (@user1,@user2)    
        SET @chat_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        insert into mesaj values (@chat_id,@user1,@mesaj_text,getdate(),@mesaj_read)
    END
END
```